# Cannot get sounds to run Kivy + PyInstaller + OSX

Tags: python, macos, kivy, pyinstaller

My installed app crashes when it tries to play a sound with this error:

```
File "kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx", line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load
kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin
```

Despite following the detailed instructions on the official packaging docs:

```
https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html
```

Has someone else successfully created a Kivy + PyInstaller + sound + OSX?

I cannot seem to be able to import the sdl2 in the spec file (below):

This line from the official packaging docs did not work for me:

> brew reinstall --with-python --build-bottle https://github.com/cbenhagen/homebrew/raw/patch-3/Library/Formula/gst-python.rb

################################################################## 100.0%

```
Error: undefined method `revision' for #<BottleSpecification:0x00000101dbf1a8>
Please report this bug:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
/Users/erikbethke/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/gst-python.rb:8:in `block in <class:GstPython>'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:101:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:101:in `bottle'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2086:in `bottle'
/Users/erikbethke/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/gst-python.rb:7:in `<class:GstPython>'
/Users/erikbethke/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/gst-python.rb:1:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:26:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:26:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:46:in `load_formula_from_path'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:101:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:174:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:92:in `klass'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:88:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:280:in `factory'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:57:in `block in resolved_formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:55:in `map'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:55:in `resolved_formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/reinstall.rb:13:in `reinstall'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:101:in `<main>'
```

Below is my spec file, note I have to comment out the sdl2 import line, otherwise I get the import error that follows:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

#                *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins + gstreamer.dep_bins)],
# from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

block_cipher = None
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_all, hookspath, runtime_hooks
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_hooks

added_files = [
         ( '/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/assets', 'assets' ),
         ( '/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/simObject/resourceBar.kv', 'simObject' ),
         ( '/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/views/fileOperations.kv', 'views' ),
         ( '/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/views/marsDialog.kv', 'views' ),
         ]

a = Analysis(['/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/marsMain.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/dist'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['_tkinter', 'Tkinter', 'enchant', 'twisted'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='mom',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          icon='/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/logo.icns',
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/assets'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='mom')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='mom.app',
             icon='/Users/erikbethke/Desktop/SMS/MarsSim/logo.icns',
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Import Error

```
175 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
175 INFO: Python: 3.6.5
180 INFO: Platform: Darwin-15.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
182 INFO: UPX is not available.
183 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in /Users/erikbethke/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/erikbethke/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-04-26_87.txt
206 INFO: [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/erikbethke/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-04-26_87.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 20180424
206 INFO: [Kivy        ] v1.10.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 20180424
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:41:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]
206 INFO: [Python      ] v3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:41:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
207 WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
207 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
     sys.exit(run())
207 WARNING: stderr:     sys.exit(run())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 94, in run
207 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 94, in run
     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
207 WARNING: stderr:     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
208 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
208 WARNING: stderr:     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in main
208 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in main
     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
208 WARNING: stderr:     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in build
209 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in build
     exec(text, spec_namespace)
209 WARNING: stderr:     exec(text, spec_namespace)
   File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
209 WARNING: stderr:   File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
 ImportError: cannot import name 'sdl2'
209 WARNING: stderr: ImportError: cannot import name 'sdl2'
```